# Limit of VSTS account with one email ID

Tags: azure-devops

My requirement is to create lots of VSTS account with one email ID (User ID) so I need to know,

how many VSTS account I can create with one email ID (User ID)?
How many Projects under one VSTS account I can create?

Please help me to get these answer so that i can take the decision accordingly. Thanks.

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: are you trying to do this via code?

Comment: Are you using the personal E-mail account or AAD E-mail account(work)?

Comment: I do have both options, manual and code.

Comment: I am using personal E-mail (Live ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isn’t any official document to be referenced for the VSTS account  limits with one email ID .

For the limitation of team projects per account, take a look at below reply from Ewald Hofman (PM of TFS) in MSFT:

> The **soft limit is indeed 300 projects** (the limit doesn't show up
>   yet, but soon will) and we have **a hard limit of 500.**

Besides, usually we suggest you use [one Team Project to rule them all](https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/).

> **The scope of a team project should be things that are related to each other.** When you work on a product that is very closely related
>   you want to have everything in a single team project. For example
>   inside Microsoft, Windows, Office and VSTS products are all in a
>   single team project.

More details please take a look at the source link: [Maximum Area nodes per level in TFS/VSTS?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a605138-48d3-440f-abb0-2b6383b81217/maximum-area-nodes-per-level-in-tfsvsts?forum=TFService)

Comment: Thanks. This information will help me to take the decision.